# Is there a standard or coding standard for WordPress string constants?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, standards

I have a set of options I want to store in a WordPress plugin and these names are likely never to change. However, I want to account for the eventuality that they do.

If `myplugin` is the name of the plugin I'm developing, I have an 'option names' named in the following style:

- `myplugin_preference_name`
- `myplugin_preference_address`

That sort of thing.

Anyway, there doesn't appear to be any sort of authority on whether using a PHP `define()` call is OK in this case or not (in the context of a WordPress plugin).

I have already had a look through the WordPress coding standards:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants in WordPress are normally written in uppercase.

You do not find that in the coding standards, because WordPress coding standards are historically weakly documented and enforced, and I would not rely too much on that document.

Also, you should consider to not introduce constants too much. You can not use a constant for everything. It needs to be one, and normally variables already do a good job.